# Proposer vs Aggregator rewards - who gets penalized?

Tags: consensus, validators, attestations

Afaik, proposers get more rewards for more attestations they include.

The issue however is that proposers grab from subnet(committee) aggregators of attestations.  My question is does the aggregator miss out on rewards if he goes offline (or only submits his attestation)?

Can I ignore attestations as the subnet aggregator and not get punished?

And secondly, what can honest, but ignored validators do?  Just go attest late to the proposer (or next block proposer?) and get part of the rewards?  How late are they if the aggregator is offline?

And in the case of a late report, who gets the rewards?  The proposer for your block or the new block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregators are not directly incentivised to do their work. There are, however, two weak indirect incentives for trying to produce good aggregate attestations and get them into blocks.

The first is that [rewards scale with participation](https://eth2book.info/capella/part2/incentives/rewards/#rewards-scale-with-participation). For example, if only 90% of expected attestations make it into blocks, then my own reward for attesting will be reduced to 90% of the maximum reward. So, if I am selected as an aggregator, and I want to maximise my own reward for attesting, then I should try to produce the best packed aggregate I can in order to maximise the overall participation. Failing to produce an aggregate, or doing it poorly, might end up in my (and everyone else's) rewards being a little lower due to fewer attestations making it into blocks.

The second is that it is the best way to ensure that my own attestation is included. When I publish my attestation to the committee subnet, the best chance for it to be included quickly in a block is for it to be picked up by an aggregator for the committee. If I am an aggregator for the committee, and I don't produce an aggregate, then I am taking the chance that one of the other aggregators will include my attestation, instead of more-or-less guaranteeing it by producing my own aggregate.

There's not a lot that you can do if your attestation is not picked up by an aggregator. It will float around the gossip network for a bit and has a chance of being picked up in a later slot by a block proposer and included as a singleton. For example, the [block at slot 8179254](https://beaconcha.in/slot/8179254#attestations) has quite a few old attestations tacked on at the end from just one or two validators, just to fill up the available slots. Some proposers do this, some don't - it may differ between client implementations.

It is always the first block proposer that includes an attestation in its block that gets the reward for it (in addition to the attestor itself), even if it is included several slots late. It will be worth less, but still worth [something](https://eth2book.info/capella/part2/incentives/rewards/#attestation-rewards).

Comment: super helpful!  Thanks Ben.  So for "If I am an aggregator for the committee, and I don't produce an aggregate, then I am taking the chance that one of the other aggregators will include my attestation", does this mean that there are multiple aggregators per subnet?  Or it would be an aggregator in another slot?

Comment: and is it the same for sync commitees?  Just thinking this may be a discouragement attack vector

Comment: Yes, there are usually multiple aggregators appointed per committee. See https://eth2book.info/capella/part2/building_blocks/aggregator/ for the details. They aggregate only for their own committee and slot.

Comment: Sync committees are almost the same, https://eth2book.info/capella/part2/building_blocks/aggregator/#sync-committee-aggregators. Would be interested in the discouragement aspect.